# passing arguments in different languages

Tags: programming-languages, parameters, arguments, return-value

can somebody please explain what is the difference between the following mechanisms of passing arguments: by value, by result, by result-value, with examples if possible, thanks in advance

Comment: have you seen this article?: http://www.arl.wustl.edu/~lockwood/class/cs306/books/artofasm/Chapter_11/CH11-2.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general info see [Evaluation strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy).

For example code you can check [HERE](http://www.exforsys.com/tutorials/c-language/call-by-value-and-call-by-reference.html).

Also C# language specification can be useful :

> **5.1.4 Value parameters**
>
> A parameter declared without a ref or
>   out modifier is a value parameter. A
>   value parameter comes into existence
>   upon invocation of the function member
>   (method, instance constructor,
>   accessor, or operator) or anonymous
>   function to which the parameter
>   belongs, and is initialized with the
>   value of the argument given in the
>   invocation. A value parameter normally
>   ceases to exist upon return of the
>   function member or anonymous function.
>   However, if the value parameter is
>   captured by an anonymous function
>   (§7.15), its life time extends at
>   least until the delegate or expression
>   tree created from that anonymous
>   function is eligible for garbage
>   collection. For the purpose of
>   definite assignment checking, a value
>   parameter is considered initially
>   assigned.
>
> **5.1.5 Reference parameters**
>
> A parameter declared with a ref
>   modifier is a reference parameter. A
>   reference parameter does not create a
>   new storage location. Instead, a
>   reference parameter represents the
>   same storage location as the variable
>   given as the argument in the function
>   member or anonymous function
>   invocation. Thus, the value of a
>   reference parameter is always the same
>   as the underlying variable. The
>   following definite assignment rules
>   apply to reference parameters. Note
>   the different rules for output
>   parameters described in §5.1.6.
>
> - A variable must be definitely assigned
>     (§5.3) before it can be passed as a
>     reference parameter in a function
>     member or delegate invocation.
> - Within a function member or anonymous    function, a reference
>     parameter is    considered initially
>     assigned.
>
> Within an instance method or instance
>   accessor of a struct type, the this
>   keyword behaves exactly as a reference
>   parameter of the struct type (§7.6.7).
>
> **5.1.6 Output parameters**
>
> A parameter declared with an out
>   modifier is an
>   output parameter. An output parameter
>   does not create a new storage
>   location. Instead, an output parameter
>   represents the same storage location
>   as the variable given as the argument
>   in the function member or delegate
>   invocation. Thus, the value of an
>   output parameter is always the same as
>   the underlying variable. The following definite
>   assignment rules apply to output
>   parameters. Note the different rules
>   for reference parameters described in
>   §5.1.5.
>
> - A variable need not be definitely    assigned before it can be passed as
>     an output parameter in a function
>     member or delegate invocation.
> - Following the normal completion of a    function member or delegate
>     invocation, each variable that was
>     passed as an output parameter is
>     considered assigned in that execution 
>     path.
> - Within a function member or anonymous    function, an output
>     parameter is    considered initially
>     unassigned.
> - Every output parameter of a function    member or anonymous
>     function must be    definitely
>     assigned (§5.3) before the    function
>     member or anonymous function
>     returns normally.
>
> Within an instance constructor of a
>   struct type, the this keyword behaves
>   exactly as an output parameter of the
>   struct type (§7.6.7).

Answer (score 0):

See C++. The Complete Reference Guide. Herbert Shildt. Third Edition. 139 page.

"Call by value. This method copies the value of an argument into the formal parameter of the subroutine. In this case, changes made to the parameter have no effect on the argument."

"Call by reference is the second way of passing arguments to a subroutine. In this
method, the address of an argument is copied into the parameter. Inside the subroutine,
the address is used to access the actual argument used in the call. This means that
changes made to the parameter affect the argument."

...

Comment: good explanation for pass by value and pass by reference. doesn't answer the question about pass by result and by result-value though